# Adding a class in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Below is a calendar in jquery that i need to add to it a class, any help on how to do so? I tried addind: addClass() but it did not work, maybe i added it falsely.

```
handler:Ext.onReady(function(){
                       $("#from").calendarsPicker({calendar: $.calendars.instance('islamic'),
                       showTrigger: '<img src="calendar.gif" alt="Popup" class="trigger">',
                       showOnFocus: false});
                        $("#from").calendarsPicker({showTrigger: '#myicon'});
                          })
```

Comment: I can't see you use addClass() in your code.

Comment: `$("#from").addClass('myClass');` .. ?